# iptables allow everything from one ip

Tags: iptables

Here's what I have.

Dual homed FreePBX box.  Everything works like a champ.  eth0 is external.  eth1 is internal.  SIP provider is at 216.234.x.x.

I'm trying to configure iptables to allow everything from eth1 and lo.  But only allow traffic from 216.234.x.x

Here are the current iptables rules I've added.

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 216.234.x.x/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

As soon as I hit enter on...

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 - j DROP
```

Inbound audio stops working.

Then when I delete that rule it works again. I'm at a loss.

Thanks,

Comment: See if this is of any use for you: http://sysadminman.net/blog/2009/iptables-for-asterisk-and-freepbx-772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for adding a LOG rule before your DROP, see if you're able to spot some necessary traffic being dropped unexpectedly.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to just have someone state the obvious ;-)  The SIP provider was sending the traffic back from a different IP.  ARGH

Comment: for future generations I used this page to figure out logging. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/

Comment: Glad it helped, I felt kind of bad posting such a simple suggestion, but I've certainly been burned by similar things before  :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is stateful firewalling - allowing packets only in one direction is obviously useless.

Fortunately, conntrack is smart so you don't have to be.

Ensure that the first rule is `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` and worry no more - the SIP helper will hopefully catch the issue of the differing IP.

You would also do well to read the iptables manpage regarding the exact arguments that the conntrack match accepts, so you can better use it in the future.

Also bear in mind that automatic setup of connection helpers will eventually be disposed of, so whilst you can currently just apply RELATED to everything, a kernel in the not-so-distant future will likely break it.